# How to avoid inconsistency between data source and PagerState in HorizontalPager of Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list named pageDatas as data source of HorizontalPager, and I can delete specific page. When the page was deleted, the exception was throwed: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 1, size: 1` at line of `CustomView`. My codes like this:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val pageDatas = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(
            PageData(
                state = 0
            )
        )
    }
    
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    HorizontalPager(pageCount = pageDatas.size, state = pagerState) { index ->
        // render page with pageData
    }

    Button(onClick = { pageDatas.removeAt(pagerState.currentPage) }) {
        Text("Delete")
    }
    
    CustomView(state = pageDatas[pagerState.currentPage])

}
```

I expecte the page can be delete correctly, and `CustomView` can be recompose with updated currentPage.

Finally, I add another variable named state, is updated when PagerState.currentPage changed. Follow is my code:

```
    var state by remember {
        mutableStateOf(initialState)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState) {
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect {
            unit = pageDatas[it].unit
        }
    }

    CustomView(state = state)
```

Comment: Try updating to latest stable version of compose - `1.5.0` - there were some changes in Pagers, you now pass `pageCount` to `rememberPagerState()` instead of `HorizontalPager`. If it doesn't help, it might be worth filing a bug.

Comment: I have updgraded `Compose` to version 1.5.0, and passed `pageCount` to `rememberPagerState`. However this did not help as the exception is still being rasied.